# Differentiation and existence

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be defined as $f(x) =  e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ for $x>0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\leq 0$. Would $f^{(3)}(x)$ exist at $x=0$? How would I show this?

Comment: Yes, of course $f^{(3)}(0)$ exists. You can do it with the same procedure you've used to prove that $f^{(2)}(0)$ exists.

Comment: I think that $f^{(3)}(0)$ is not defined, but $\lim_{x\to 0} f^{(3)}(x) = 0$.

Comment: this can count as a definition of $f^{(3)}(0)$

Comment: @Math1000: $f^{(3)}(0)$ is definitely defined. The fact that its calculation involves different-looking functions for negative and positive $x$ doesn't change that fact.